# ImportError: cannot import name setup

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools

I installed setuptools with python 2.7.2 but still get the error when trying to launch `python setup.py install`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 22, in <module
from setuptools import setup
ImportError: cannot import name setup
```

Comment: What is your setuptools version?

Comment: I installed setuptools-18.2 via the ez_setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
```

to my setup.py and putting the ez_setup.py into the same folder as my setup.py